# upload a file to server without using a form?

Tags: php, html, file-upload, curl, http-headers

We imagine that form;

```
<form action="http://api.blabla.com/huhu.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="files[]" />
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
```

I want to upload files to this server without using the form which is above.

I tried this with php curl but I could not.

I want it because I have very large number of files to upload. And this should be automatic with cron jobs.

Comment: You can use file_get_contents.

See : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003989/upload-a-file-using-file-get-contents][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003989/upload-a-file-using-file-get-contents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example of file uploading with cURL you could start with:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://api.blabla.com/huhu.php');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'files[]' => '@/path/to/file',
    ),
));
if (false === ($res = curl_exec($ch))) {
    die("Upload failed: " . curl_error($ch));
}
```

The string `'@/path/to/file'` has a special meaning because it starts with an `@`; the string that directly follows it should contain the path of a file you wish to upload.