# POSTing a file via PHP curl

Tags: php, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [upload a file to server without using a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036799/upload-a-file-to-server-without-using-a-form)

I'am able to run this succesfully on command line:

`curl -v -H "a-token: myTokenValue" -H "content-type: application/xml" -X POST --data-binary @/tmp/myfile_2_3.xml -A "My Wonderful Agent" http://example.com/url`

How do I get this in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Using POST with file uploading :-)

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents("/tmp/myfile_2_3.xml");
$defaults = array(
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "post",
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://example.com/url",
    CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => 1,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 4,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fileContents,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("a-token" => "myTokenValue", "Content-Type" => "application/xml"),
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, ($options + $defaults));
if( ! $result = curl_exec($ch))
{
    trigger_error(curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Because your example does nothing but a GET. It doesn't upload a file, which is what the OP wants. You've basically said "solve your problem by solving your problem". (and no, I didn't downvote, but I'm tempted)

Comment: I fixed it. It uses cURL to post a file directly to a URL now, including all the headers and stuff.

Comment: @Mohamed Nuur It works, thanks. The trick is `file_get_contents()`  as argument for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, not in an array. `CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNET`, `CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` are not needed, in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it to [`exec()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Comment: It is what I would like to avoid. Is there any other alternative out there?

Comment: What's wrong with this, and why didn't you say so in your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, I didn't explain enough about it. I have the request system in a framework, where I can obviously set the cURL options and ovverride the the request method, which already gives me the response from my request. Since I have to work with the response from my request, I have to find the right way to _translate_ the cURL command into PHP's cURL options.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/uploading-a-file-using-curl-in-php.html) for how to use it without the extra overhead of file_get_contents, which was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036799/upload-a-file-to-server-without-using-a-form).

Comment: The `file_get_contents` function might be the solution, since the array for `CURL_POSTFIELDS` gets to the `-F` curl option, which is not what I want in my query. The `@` character to submit a filename in the `CURL_POSTFIELDS` array wants an index; it is not allowed to pass `@myFileName.ext` except in an array (from the PHP manual: _"As of PHP 5.2.0, files thats passed to this option with the @ prefix must be in array form to work."_).