# posting information and getting back the response in PHP

Tags: php, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [upload a file to server without using a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036799/upload-a-file-to-server-without-using-a-form)
>   [POSTing a file via PHP curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048144/posting-a-file-via-php-curl)

I have a xml file with me which is of size 10 KB. how can I send this xml file's content
using http post method to some other page at other domain ? I am using PHP 5.3 in Windows with XAMPP and I can use the CURL extension. I cannot use the Http_Request method which
can be used after placing the php_http.dll. Can someone help with any alternatives using native PHP or CURL extension, so that I can post this xml content to some place using http and http request.

Comment: what exactly are you trying send and to where?  What is their API/specs/Docs/etc?  Please provider a clearer description with actual code you've attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://url.com/post.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'xml=' . file_get_contents('xml.xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
?>
```

I believe that's what you wanted? Unless you meant a file upload.