# how to send file with file_get_contents?

Tags: php, rest, file-get-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Upload a file using file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003989/upload-a-file-using-file-get-contents)

I want to send a jpg file to another server with `file_get_contents`.

I use this for `POST` data but don't works if I put my jpg file in the `data` array

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'collection' => 'test',
        'data' =>  array('name'=>'Test name','Surname'=>'Test Surname')
    )
);

$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => "POST",
        'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
                "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
                "Content-Length: ".strlen($postdata)."\r\n",
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://localhost/test/index.php/save-doc', false, $context);
```

Comment: Consider using CURL for this task.

Comment: I dont understand why you are using file_get_contents when you want to post something.

Comment: `file_get_contents` is meant to read a file, not to send it. To send something, use a different method, like [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) as [AleksG](http://stackoverflow.com/users/717214/aleks-g) suggested.

Comment: You have to use a multi-part `Content-type` header. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003989/upload-a-file-using-file-get-contents

Comment: There seems to be a bit of confusion here. Yes `file_get_contents` is meant to read files, but it can also read **responses from page requests**. Using the stream context it _should_ indeed be possible to **send** data using it.