# PHP How to download file to server - Connecion timeout

Tags: php

I want download this file

```
http://193.111.141.206:8000/live/mirko/mirko/22.m3u8
```

and want to save on server.

I have this php script:

```
<?php
$ts1 = http://193.111.141.206:8000/live/mirko/mirko/22.m3u8;
file_put_contents("stream.m3u8", fopen($ts1, 'r'));
?>
```

I get this error

```
Warning: fopen( http://193.111.141.206:8000/live/mirko/mirko/22.m3u8): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /home/.../download.php on line 25
```

Manualy I can open this file, but php says Connection timed out...
Anybody know a solution?

Comment: `file_put_contents` expects a string for its input. you're passing in a file handle, which will never work. you need `file_put_contents(.., file_get_contents(...))`. and since the connection times out anyways, you need to investigate why. either the remote site is blocking your server, or your server's firewall is preventing apache/php from opening network connections.

Comment: @strangeqargo: uh, what uploads? ignoring all the other problems, OP is trying to download that url into a local .m3u8 file.

Comment: The code you have shown here will not parse (there are no quotes around the URL). The other line is semantically incorrect.

Comment: I think you need to use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) before calling `file_put_contents`.

Comment: oh, sorry, I somehow got an idea author wants to use file_put_contents to upload file to server. Maybe because of this "download file to server" phrase. Missed this handle thing

Comment: I tried `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` but Connection timed out.. @MarcB maybe something blocked this function. Can download with another function?

Comment: Firewall has been disabled and I have same error

Comment: We always used CURL+PHP for this type of work, but, maybe you should look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003989/upload-a-file-using-file-get-contents

Comment: Tried curl and same error. How to use wget in php for dowload?

Comment: This definitely something internal and it will be hard to diagnose it. For me this `file_get_contents('http://193.111.141.206:8000/live/mirko/mirko/22.m3u8');` works like a charm.

Comment: @Aleksandar: if f_g_c can't do it, then other functions probably can't either, especially if the problem is somewhere OUTSIDE of your server, e.g. the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody.
I do website transfer to another server and `file_get_contents`, `file_put_contents` functions works.

P.S.

`exec('wget http://google.com/index.html -whateverargumentisusedforoutput', $array);`

server saw this code as malware :)